# Calculated column based on specific elements from another site column

Tags: calculated-column, site-column, calculated-column-formula

I have this site column in a Sharepoint 2013 list showing a few deadlines.

[image]

I need to create a calculated column next to the one in the picture, that gives as a result the number of days between one date and the following. 
On Excel is quite simple (you do A2-A1), but how can I do that on Sharepoint?
Problem is, these dates have to be updated every now and then, so I cannot just create another column with the same dates and then use the DIFDATE formula between the two site columns. Any idea?

Comment: Are you talking about diferents rows? Not posible

Comment: Yes, I would have loved to do that. I just found out it is not possible. There's not even a workaround for this?

Comment: You could do this with a SharePoint 2013 workflow and the 'Find Interval Between Dates' action. The challenge would be keeping the items in order. Worst case you could build a REST API call to GET the list data sorted by Actual Date and loop through it to find the date before/date after and calculate as needed. Time consuming and a little process-intensive depending on the size of your list but it's doable.

Comment: event handler in c# is a good option

Comment: anyone knows a tutorial or a guide on how to follow your advices? I think they are both beyond my abilities...

Comment: With considerable less programming you can link MS-Access to your SP list and write a SQL Query

Comment: Hi everyone! In the end I found a solution to my problem by first rendering the list items in a jQuery datatable, and then following the indications given in this link: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/43460/how-to-perform-calculations-over-different-rows-of-one-column